# I cannot connect to the internet on a Windows 10 device but can on others

Tags: windows-10, internet, internet-connection

I have a router that I can connect to from another computer, but not from my Windows 10 desktop that is connected via Ethernet cable. The router panel looks OK - `line status : connected`, the maximum rate updates regularly, but the current rate is fixed.

However the Windows network panel indicates no network and there is no browser connection. What definitions can I check and change in Windows 10 in order to solve this problem?

Ethernet status: no internet access, but the activity is always updated (10MB received in a few minutes).

```
Ipconfig :Connection-specific DNS Suffix. 
Description...........: Realtek PCIe GBE 
Family Controller DHCP Enabled........... NO 
Autoconfiguration Enabled Yes 
IP44 Address..... 192.168.1.10( Preferred) 
Subnet Mask 1255.255.255.0 
Default Gateway 192.168.1.1 
DNS Servers 91.205.152.174 91.205.152.204 
NetBIOS over tcpip.... Enabled
```

Comment: @OMGsh - Please edit your question to include the information from your temporary commentary

Comment: Ipconfig :Connection-specific DNS Suffix.
Description...........: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
DHCP Enabled...........NO
Autoconfiguration Enabled Yes
IP44 Address..... 192.168.1.10( Preferred)
Subnet Mask 1255.255.255.0
Default Gateway 192.168.1.1
DNS Servers 91.205.152.174
91.205.152.204
NetBIOS over tcpip.... Enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During comments we found out, that a user defined DNS server was set and "nslookup test.de" gave a timeout.

To fix the name resolution on the Windows machine there are 3 solutions possible:
 a) change the network interface from static to DHCP, to use the DNS server provided by the ISP (a DHCP reservation may be done on the router if needeed, so the IP adress will not change in the future)

b) or use the router's IP as DNS server (routers will usually forward this to ISP's DNS servers)

c) or use a freely available DNS server, like for example 8.8.8.8 from Google. For additional security, a filtering DNS server like [Quad9](https://www.quad9.net/) may be used

Comment: Wow. I've  changed IP assignment  to DHCP auto - problem solved. Is this the preferred settings or are there cases when I should change it back to Manual?

Comment: Only under special of circumstances you want to force a fixed IP - for example when you have a web server on the PC, which the phone should be able to access **and** when the router does not support DHCP reserverations. For more info you may read [this article](https://www.lifewire.com/using-static-ip-address-on-private-computer-818404).