# Is there a way to test a router's health?

Tags: router

There are many indications for router failures ( bad connection, high line attenuation, bad snr margin) but all this can be caused by bad infrastructure. Is there a method to test the router's health?

An example of a bad looking router panel on a 15M plan:[image]

Comment: As always, debugging is done by changing parts in separation: Carry the router to some other place with different infrastructure. If it works in that place but not in your place, the router is broken. Alternatively, connect up a friend's router in your place: If this one works but yours doesn't, your router is broken.

Comment: I looks like you are asking because of a [specific issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1547574/i-cannot-connect-to-the-internet-on-a-win10-device-but-can-on-others). Before checks on a technical level, you should consider to check the router brand's lifecycle page - if there are no security updates anymore or the latest firmware is 10 years old, it may be a good idea to buy a new one.

Comment: I ask because whenever someone has a problem the network company blames the router. I wish there was a way to test the router based on the panel data for example. Testing in another place is a good idea but it's not always possible.

Comment: I want to test that the unit can synchronize to the ISP and provide good connection to a wired PC. And especially that it does not short circuit (that's what ISPs always say the router and landline phone do in order not to send a technician). Of course having a second router is beneficial but most people don't have one and also this unit can be defective. I especially talk about cases when their is mediocre connection when the attenuation or bandwidth are bad or there are many connection drops.

Comment: If a router has a hardware issue, it's either going to work or it's not & will likely not present with an intermittent issue.  If it's software [firmware] related, the manufacturer can often provide a debugging image to be flashed that will allow user-accessible log output _(that being said, opensource firmware like OpenWrt is preferred if the router is supported since router manufacturers consider a consumer router EoL [End of Life] after 1yr, 2yrs at most)_.  The wrong config settings on a router can also result in throughput issues, such as not setting a WiFi channel, as can a bad LAN cable

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. If neighbors have the same connection speeds way below maximum, a long "last mile" (cable length until the DSLAM) would be the problem. As adding more DSLAMs is expensive for ISPs, you may check if there are any other ISPs in your area that provide fast internet through TV cable or optical fiber (4G would only be a workaround if the needed data volume is small, Netflix on 4G would not be a good idea). To just get the current speed working more stable, you may ask your ISP to be switched to another DSLAM port.

Comment: I will try to solve this with my ISP. Somehow my neighbors, with the same ISP, are on different infrastructure  (I can't get the speed plan they get). Again, I hoped there was a way to look at the panel and know that I have to buy a new router without dealing with neighbors or  the ISP and or for a technician. But I understand now that there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

A) To verify that the router's modem (including cable) is ok and just the line is bad:
testing at a different place is the only chance to do that

B) but as your goal is not the router itself but a stable internet connection:
only trying a different (if possible newer) router at your place without improvement will convice the ISP to further investigate.
Buying/borrowing are not the only ways to do that: if you exchange routers with a friendly neighbor for example, you will get results for A) and B) at the same time.

Comment: Knowing that there is no panel-data-based solution is better than knowing nothing al all. But exchanging units with neighbors will have to wait for a Corona free days.

Comment: The data shown in the router's web interface is not a proof (although for example [AVM routers](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.teltarif.de%2Ffritzbox-kennwerte-dsl%2Fnews%2F61899.html) give many details), but adding a screenshot to your question doesn't hurt. If screenshots from similar routers of your neighbors show much better results, you could still send them to your ISP.